# Linked Lists in Lua

Tags: lua, linked-list, lua-table

I've recently been looking up linked lists in Lua and have a quick question that so far I haven't been able to find an answer for

```
local head = nil

head = {next = head, value = "d"}
head = {next = head, value = "c"}
head = {next = head, value = "b"}
head = {next = head, value = "a"}

local entry = head

while entry do
  print(entry.value)

  entry = entry.next
end
```

This will end up printing out "a,b,c,d". I understand why it would print out backwards, as the first 'node' available would be the final one created (with value = a). My question is why the 'head's created before the final one still exist and have not simply been overwritten in the memory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you mean by "overwritten in the memory"? Nothing you're doing would cause that to happen.

Let's look at what you're doing step by step.

```
local head = nil
```

There now exists a local variable called `head`. It has the value `nil`.

```
head = {next = head, value = "d"}
```

Let's break this down into the sequence of operations here. This is equivalent to the following:

```
do
  local temp = {}
  temp.next = head  --This is still `nil`
  temp.value = "d"
  head = temp
end
```

Every table you construct is a unique value. So let's call this first table `table-d`. It is constructed, stored in the temporary variable `temp`. The table is given a `next` value of `nil`. And it gets a `value` value of `"d"`. And the result is stored in the local variable `head`.

So now `head` has the value `table-d`. Next step:

```
head = {next = head, value = "c"}
```

Same thing:

```
do
  local temp = {}
  temp.next = head  --Not nil anymore.
  temp.value = "c"
  head = temp
end
```

OK, we create a new table. For the sake of clarity, we'll call this table `table-c`.

We store this in `temp`. We then set it's `next` field to the value in `head`. That value is `table-d`. We set the `value` field to `"c"`. And then store `table-c` into `head`.

The `table-c` table looks like this:

```
{
  next = { value = "d" }
  value = "c"
}
```

That is the table stored in `head`.

This continues like this. So where would something be "overwritten"?

Comment: Thanks this totally clarified things. I forgot that `head` would just act as a pointer to a table.